# Find how many times pattern accrues in binary number using C

Tags: c, algorithm, binary

Load a 32-bit non-negative integer (unsigned int) and an 8-bit pattern (unsigned int). It is not necessary to check the loaded numbers. Load both numbers in the decimal number system.

Determine the number of times a given pattern appears in the binary notation of a loaded 32-bit number.

It is not allowed to use the string.h library and aggregate data types.

For example:

```
32-bit number  514  00000000 00000000 00000010 00000010
 8-bit number    2                             00000010
```

So it should print that number `2` accrues 2 times.

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. I've tried to keep a counter that counts streek, but it become to complicated to quickly.

Comment: Create a mask and bitshift the 32-bit number.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution for specifically 8-bit patterns and 32-bit numbers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) // 32 bits = 4 bytes
    if ((number & 0xFF << i * 8) >> i * 8 == pattern) 
        count++;
```

The general idea is, for every 8-bit sequence in the number, mask it (set all other bits to 0 by `&`'ing the number by `0xFF` shifted however many bits required) and shift it however many bits are required to bring the masked sequence to the least significant position. [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/UdWP7vH9c) is a live working example.

---